# Drawing star-like figure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I had to plot this in matlab :
[image]

so I wrote the following code:

```
x=[0.9 1 0.9 -0.9 0.7 0.7 -0.9 0.9];
y=[-1 0 1 -0.5 -0.8 0.8 -0.4 -1];
plot(x,y);
```

but this gives me:  [image]

Is this method insufficient to draw the first figure....Is there some other short method for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do better positioning your data points

```
nPoints = 7;
th = linspace(-2*pi, 2*pi, 2*nPoints+1);%// extra point to close the curve
r = 1;
x = r*cos(th);
y = r*sin(th);
scatter( x, y, 'ro' );
hold on;
plot( x(1:2:end), y(1:2:end), 'b-' );
axis equal;
```

Resulting with:
[image]

BTW, this code works for any odd `nPoints` - just try ;)

Comment: thanks for answer,but can you please explain me this:when I delete the semicolon at the end of x = r*cos(th);
                                   y = r*sin(th);   why does the figure repeats itself....

Comment: MATLAB prints the value of expressions that don't end with a semicolon. It's repeating itself because it's displaying the plot again due to the missing semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you want to construct a [`star polygon`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_polygon), which has the property that all points are equidistant to its neighboring points, and all points lie on the same circle.

First, we generate the desired angles `a` (measured from the x-axis to a line that connects the origin with the desired point, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle)). Based on the polygon, we rearrage the angles in such a way that a desired number of points is skipped (in the code below, this is done by using among others `repmat` - but many alternatives exist).

To convert the angles to actual points in the plane, we take sine and cosine values, and then we can plot the dots and lines. Putting this together results in the following code, which results in the dersired figure

```
n = 7;
a = linspace(0,2*pi,n+1);
skip = 1;

b = [repmat(a(1:end-1),1,skip+1) a(end)];
a = b(1:skip+1:end);

figure;
clf;
hold on;
plot(cos(a),sin(a),'b-');
plot(cos(a(1:end-1)),sin(a(1:end-1)),'ro');

axis([-1 1 -1 1])
axis equal
```

---

A little less involved would be to compute the vector `a` like this:

```
a = mod(linspace(0,(skip+1)*2*pi,n+1),(skip+1)*2*pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried manually:

```
x = [-0.4 0.6 1 0.6 -0.4 -0.8 -0.8];
y = [-0.9 -0.7 0 0.7 0.9 0.4 -0.4];

x_ = [x,x];
y_ = [y,y];

figure;
hold on;
for ii=1:numel(x),
    scatter(x(ii),y(ii),'ro');
    plot([x_(ii),x_(ii+1+1)],[y_(ii),y_(ii+1+1)],'b-');
end
axis([-1 1 -1 1]);
```

And I get his:

[image]